# Save gzip compression stream to destination C#.Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, zip, gzip

I'm using DotNetZIP(Ionic utility) to ZIP my files.But my client says "no" to it.They wanted me to use WinZip to ZIP the file.
I'm using MS provied GZIP(its OK for client) like this:

```
using(GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
```

How can I save the compression stream?it seems that there is no method available for VS2008/.Net3.5.

Searched on net but not got any suitable link or solution.Could any one please help on this?

Comment: I used this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx as a solution.But this is **not for** VS2008(this is working in VS2010).Please share if any one have other ideas to do this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.90).aspx

```
public static void Compress(FileInfo fi)
        {
            // Get the stream of the source file. 
            using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
            {
                // Prevent compressing hidden and already compressed files. 
                if ((File.GetAttributes(fi.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden)
                        != FileAttributes.Hidden & fi.Extension != ".gz")
                {
                    // Create the compressed file. 
                    using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".gz"))
                    {
                        using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile,
                                CompressionMode.Compress))
                        {
                            // Copy the source file into the compression stream.
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int numRead;
                            while ((numRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                            {
                                Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                                fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), outFile.Length.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```